# Difference of Implicit Differentiation and Isolating y

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I was tasked to find the second derivative of the equation $2y = x^{2}y - 10$.

I tried solving it in two ways: using implicit differentiation and isolating $y$ in the equation.

If using implicit differentiation, I get $y'' = \frac{(2-x^{2})(2y + \frac{4x^{2}y}{2-x^{2}}) + 4x^{2}y}{(2-x^{2})^{2}}$.

If isolating $y$, since $y=\frac{-10}{2-x^{2}}$, I get $y''=\frac{-20(3x^{2} + 2)}{(2-x^{2})^{3}}$.

Since I am getting different answers, is there a "more correct" way of approaching this problem? It was not specified that we should use implicit differentiation.

Comment: Both ways are correct. If you replace $y$ in the first, you should get the second.

Comment: Although they are the same, I think the derivative in terms of only the independent variable would be “preferred” as the more simplified form.

Comment: Tried plugging in $y$ in the first, and it worked! Did not think of that. Thank you very much.